# What is this in GNOME tweaks?

Tags: 22.10, gnome-tweaks

[image: image of what i'm talking about:]

What is the field with *(None)* next to a folder icon?

I have alreay looked for a file that it may accept, but to no avail.

Comment: It looks like a shell theme, but viewing the whole window you're display may provide a better understanding of the little you pasted.

Comment: AFAIK, it appears to be that no theme folder is selected.